# Target only a selector with this

Tags: jquery

Not sure how to explain this, but I would like to target a selector only within `this`.

So lets say I have

```
 <ul>
   <li class=a></li>
   <li class=b></li>
   <li class=c></li>
 </ul>
```

And I execute this:

```
 $("li").each(function(i,v){
   $(".a",$(this)).append("1");
   $(".b",$(this)).append("2");
   $(".c",$(this)).append("3");
 });
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected, but I'm sure there is a way that it does.

I've tried using `if hasClass("a")`,etc. but I would like to avoid that route if possible. Any suggestions?

I also know I can do `$("li:eq("+i+").a")` as a selector, but I am trying to use `this` here.

Unfortunately this doesn't work either: `$(this).find(".a")`

Comment: Explain us what are you trying to do. Iterate over each li element, then set its text to be the index of the element among the rest of its siblings?

Comment: You're probably looking for .filter(), `$(this).filter('.a').append("1");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something more like this

```
$("li").each(function(i,v){
   if ( $(this).hasClass('a') ) $(this).text("1");
   if ( $(this).hasClass('b') ) $(this).text("2");
   if ( $(this).hasClass('c') ) $(this).text("3");
});
```

It's the LI that has the class, so you have to check it, right now you're using the context selector wich searches for an element with that class inside the LI.

Also note that when you're not appending elements but really just setting the elements text, use `text()`

As a final sidenote, your example could also be done like this

```
$("li").text(function(i) { return i+1 })
```

But I'm guessing it's just an example and that you didn't just want a number ?

Comment: So i have to use hasClass?

Comment: @ZeeTee - Or `.is('.a')`

Comment: I think `.is` may be what i'm looking for

Comment: In this case it's the same thing, but `hasClass()` is more efficient than `is()`

Comment: But note that, `.is()` invokes the full selector parser, whereas `hasClass()` only needs to check the `className` property.